# JsSip Answer addstream not called

Tags: windows, asterisk, jssip

We are using jssip 3.3.4 to handle incoming calls.

We are seeing a few systems where the call is not answered when the user clicks the answer button.

The answer button essentially does:

```
session.answer(callOptions);
session.connection.addEventListener('addstream', function (e) {
 console.warn('call answered');
});
```

On most systems we see the log message 'call answered' and life is good.

On a small number of windows systems (windows 10 1909) the addstream event doesn't fire and we don't see the log message 'call answered' and the call also isn't answered.

We don't think the problem is network related because in at least one instances we have two pc's in the same office. One works and one doesn't.

The SIP server is asterisk 16.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the event `addstream` is deprecated in favor of the `ontrack` event see [RCT docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onaddstream). Try switching the events does that fix the problem?